# Eclipse debugger not working properly. Not opening perspective and not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I am using eclipse(Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.1 Release (4.7.1)). Currently I am experiencing problems debugging my project. When I run a junit in debug mode, it doesn't go into debug perspective and doesn't stop at breakpoints. The "skip break points" button in not pressed. Also when I try debugging another project I have no problems, but in this it just won't work. If you need any more info, I would gladly provide it.

Comment: Why the older release? Are there breakpoints set? Is Eclipse responsible for compiling your sources, or are you relying on a tool like Maven? Which Java Runtime version, and by whom?

Comment: Is the TestNG library included in your project, by chance?

Comment: TestNG? Also I am using Maven and JDK8, yes breakpoints are set

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't answer my question. If you are using TestNG, I've experienced that this library is not compatible with JUnit: It prevents JUnit tests from being executed.

Comment: No, I am not using it

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, but I'm using Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). The debugger stops at some breakpoints, but not at some others. I also have proof from my server log that the code was runned in that specific file where I have breakpoints, but in some strange way, the eclipse debugger doesn't recognize it.

Comment: do you have `blue ball with tick` or `blue ball without tick` as a breakpoint when you start debugging ?